# Há vantagens em usar little endianess?

Tags: ciência-da-computação, arquitetura-computadores

Hoje as principais arquiteturas usam *little endianess*. Existe uma vantagem clara para seu uso? Devo me preocupar quando estou programando? Em que situação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo uma [resposta no SE.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/95573/389) *little endian* é mais vantajoso porque valores de vários tamanhos podem ser interpretados com um endereço válido sem nenhuma operação extra. Há quem conteste isto.

Embora possa ser pouco intuitivo para um humano ter o mais significativo vindo depois, para a CPU ela se vira bem.

Na maior parte das vezes não precisa se preocupar com isso. Se estiver manipulando bits de dados aí precisa se preocupar.

Comment: Se você estiver lendo `bare` de uma interface de comunicação (sockets, por exemplo), isso pode interferir em sua vida. Esse é o mesmo problema com serialização proprietária, precisando escrever do zero. Isso é tema de uma possível resposta aguardada?, porque pelo visto você já domou todos os demais tópicos que eu tenho conhecimento sobre o assunto... E também é importante no design de máquinas virtuais